# Override a button using lightning component in Salesforce

Tags: javascript, html, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

What I'm trying to do is to recreate the "New" button in custom object's list views. The only difference between the existing standard "New" and the one I'm trying to create is that so I could control which recordtypes to show and which to hide. The 17 record types that I need to hide are being used to create records ONLY by using a flow. I have tried creating it myself and searching for similar codes but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest please use the out of box salesforce profile settings to control record type assignments.

For instance, lete say you have 3 record types A,B,C.

A,B should be visible to Profile 1

C should be visible to Profile 2

You can go to profile settings and Assign relavant record types for each profiles.

[image: please find the image]

Comment: I actually need these record types to be assigned, because the record types that I'm trying to hide are used for creating records ONLY by launching a flow. Sorry for not clarifying this detail in the post earlier.